# how to write IDENTITY(1,1) and default value in google bigquery when define a table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is a sql server create table statement. How to write the default 0 and IDENTITY(1,1) in bigquery ?  I google it and don't get solution. Thank you so much.

```
create table temp 
( 

    a INT DEFAULT 0,
    b smallint NULL,
    c smallint NULL,
    d datetime NULL,
    e datetime NULL,
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have Primary Keys, and **IDENTITY** is not applicable.

If you migrate data, you need to choose `INT64` or `STRING`